# java: Dynamically add line number to code at compile time

Tags: java, log4j, java-compiler-api

A compiled class file is aware which piece of code was on which line number in original java file. I want to use this feature.

```
public class A{                                     //1
                                                    //2
    int line; // maybe some modifiers if required   //3
                                                    //4
    public void method1(){                          //5
        System.out.println(line);                   //6
    }                                               //7
                                                    //8
    public void method2(){                          //9
        System.out.println(line);                   //10
    }

}
```

On compile time I'd like this to become `6` for `method1` and `10` for `method2` just like it does for final variables. So when I run the code I get the output

```
6
10
```

If I shift some code up or down, the compiler will handle it and I won't have to worry about that. 
I need this for logging purpose. Log4j is able to get me the same output but it gets line number from thread stacktrace and its not efficient as mentioned in their documentation.
[**%L:  Used to output the line number from where the logging request was issued.
WARNING Generating caller location information is extremely slow and should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.**](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html). I believe this work around will be much more efficient.

Is it possible for a programmer to use this feature and insert line numbers in code at compile time? I know it's possible for compiler but does it expose a public api for others?

Comment: Well, you could try to achieve that,... check javassist, this thing can manipulate bytecode (no compiler-thingy). But what the heck do you want to log, so the line number is necessary? I'm pretty sure, there are more elegant ways to achieve, whatever you what to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the line number at Runtime, not compile time.

You can do it inspecting the stacktraces.

```
Thread.getAllStackTraces();
```

Will give give you a map of the stacktraces for each running Thread.

Just check it out and see how it looks like:

```
    Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> allStackTraces = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
    for (StackTraceElement[] elements: allStackTraces.values()) {
        for (StackTraceElement e: elements) {
            System.out.println(e.getClassName() + " " + e.getLineNumber());
        }

    }
```

So, if you know what Thread and Object you want to inspect. Sure, you can get the line number.

Comment: This is probably what log4j does. Plus this will give me line numbers at runtime and not compile time.